# How do i find the underlying C-code for igraph's shortest_paths?

Tags: c, r, igraph

I want to look at the code for the igraph function `distances` I'd like to look at the implementation of the Dijkstra algorithm, to see if it is possible to make a change such that as soon as any path, between a fixed source and target, exceeds a threshold then that path is terminated in the search.

I can see that the function calls `C_R_igraph_shortest_paths` but I can't find this in the igraph package information for R or C on Github. I know the distances function is held in the `structural.properties.R` file but I haven't got any further than that.

I haven't had to look at this depth before so I may have missed something obvious.

Comment: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/c517ad26e537bbdf363a1f6f9cabd66040664fdd/src/structural_properties.c

Answer (score 0):

Look at igraph's C interface:

- https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Structural.html#idm470927281168

The source is on GitHub:

- https://github.com/igraph/igraph/

Look at `structural_properties.c`.

> I'd like to look at the implementation of the Dijkstra algorithm, to see if it is possible to make a change such that as soon as any path, between a fixed source and target, exceeds a threshold then that path is terminated in the search.

Yes, this is possible, and there is an open issue for it. PRs are welcome!

- https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/720